# Rotating Character when I'm rotating camera - 3D game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using MouseLook.cs to rotate the camera through a GameObject empty. It works perfectly but I want to rotate also my character at the same speed as MouseX rotating. I tried to use THIS in my "movement character" script but It doesn't follow properly the rotating camera speed, I don't know why :S

```
public float sensitivityX = 15f;   
transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")* sensitivityX, 0);
```

I searched on internet and tried various combinations but no one worked as I wanted.

[image: GameObject + Camera with MouseLook.cs]

I just want to do something like normal 3rd person Hack'n'Slash camera (like S4League, Trove, etc.).
And If anyone is asking If I followed the tutorial BurgZerg, I already did it and it isn't what I'm looking for.

Thank you in advance who'll help me :)

Comment: you'll need a `* Time.deltaTime` in there to achieve frame rate independence. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

Comment: I already tried this before but It's the same :/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to worry about other camera modes and your camera will always be behind your player then simply rotate your character instead of the camera with it attached to your character as a child positioned behind them.

This way when your character rotates, the camera follows at the same speed of rotation as it is a child game-object.

Comment: My character disappear if I do this :/

Comment: I'm not sure how that is possible, is your camera pointing at your character?

Comment: I posted a picture, look on that. The camera is a child into "KnightPllayer", my character. I'm using an empty GameObject to rotate it when I'm moving my mouse. I did it because If I put mouse look.cs at camera, I rotate the camera and so It won't work properly. If I put mouse look.cs at KnightPlayer, It won't work the same because rotate the entire character in Y and X.

Comment: Just search one game I mentioned on Youtube to see what I want to do.

Comment: Just restrict the movement for the characters rotation on the X axis - that way you can pitch your camera without making your character rotate "up and down". Then put your heirarchy as KnightPlayer(withMouseScript) > Camera(lookAt(Character))